# &D3DXVECTOR3 causes error C2102 '&' requires l-value

Tags: direct3d9

first time here.
Im trying to move the .png file using direct3d 9 function: &D3DXVECTOR3 but when I run local windows debugger it shows '&' require l-value error. I tried to search for similar case using direct3d9 but I found nothing. I would like to know what is the cause of the error and how could I fix it.

```
sprite->Draw(pointer, NULL, NULL, &D3DXVECTOR3(32, 32, 0), D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));
```

I use NULL instead of D3DXVECTOR3 at first and it runs perfectly but when change to D3DXVECTOR3 it shows the error.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the address of a temporary object like this is not C++ standard conformant.

Microsoft Visual C++ has historically accepted this usage as a "language extension", and it still does unless you are building with `/permissive-` (i.e. Conformance Mode) enabled. Without `/permissive-`, at Warning Level 4 it still emits a C4238 warning.

clang/LLVM for Windows will also accept this usage, but outputs a `-Waddress-of-temporary` warning.

The conformant solution is to create a named temporary:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 v(32, 32, 0);
sprite->Draw(pointer, NULL, NULL, &v, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));
```

> You should note that you are using legacy Direct3D 9, the [deprecated D3DX9 library](https://aka.ms/dxsdk), and the deprecated D3DXMath library. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-). These days, the recommendation is to use Direct3D 11, [DirectXMath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/ovw-xnamath-progguide), and the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki) `SpriteBatch` instead.